# How to start project for ios app in kotlin?in which tool?

Tags: ios, kotlin

I want to start ios app in kotlin. can anyone know how to set up the project and which tool I have to use for that? thanks in advance

Comment: use [**AppCode (IDE) by JetBrains**](http://developine.com/kotlin-native-ios-development-multiplatform-project/)

Comment: thanks dude@Anbu.karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes we can develop ios app in kotlin in appcode, but it depends XCode for ui